# Can we route one project from another project in angular

Tags: angular2-routing

I have two independent project , say project1 and Project2 . I want two route to project2 from project1 and vice versa according to some condition.  they are two independent project

can we achieve this  in angular 2

Comment: Please help me i bound to make one project as sub-project of other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In angular communication of two project say project1 and project2 is not possible .
we have to make mode by "ng g module" command

eg
ng g module project1
ng g module project2

both project are independent module of a project and can communicate with each other by using service